# org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, tomcat

I am working on a project which uses GWT on client side, Tomcat Apache server, MySQL, Hibernate with JPA. I am also using annotations and EntityManager
My folder structure is as follows:

```
+build
+java
   +com
   +META-INF
       persistence.xml
+webcontent
   +WEB-INF
```

I am getting following output in the console among other info

```
INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  - hibernate.properties not found
INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  - Bytecode provider name : javassist
```

I also tried placing persistence.xml inside web-inf/meta-inf but I still get same error.
This is happening only when I operate it on server. If I test it locally using a main class, it works.
Any idea why it can not find properties file

Comment: Did you try `webcontent/META-INF/persistence.xml` ?

Comment: Why do you think it's an error? It's an information message, your program should work fine after it.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate just informs you that it wasn't able to find file named hibernate.properties.
If you would like to get rid of this log message create webcontent/WEB-INF/hibernate.properties

You can provide vendor specific properties in the persistence.xml directly like this :

```
<properties>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
</properties>
```